# Simulating Multiple Table Inheritance in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, multiple-inheritance

By now, everyone knows that Linq-to-SQL does not natively support multiple table inheritance (a.k.a., table-per-subtype) and that you can use other ORM frameworks such as the Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc. instead if you want native support for multiple table inheritance (reference the SO question "[Multiple Inheritance in LINQtoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782858/multiple-inheritance-in-linqtosql)" if you have any doubts).

However, supposing that you did want to use (or were limited to use) Linq-to-SQL as your ORM layer, has anyone identified a simple and straight-forward design strategy for *simulating* multiple table inheritance in Linq-to-SQL projects so that client code can be written against the Linq-to-SQL layer using a natural, object-oriented API?

Comment: Linq-to-Sql is not a ORM, it's just responsible to translate ExpressionTrees in SQL

Answer (score 0):

I think **Sam** had the good answer : *Linq2Sql* doesn't seems to be able to do that.
But as long as you just want to *simulate* this behavior, I would do something like that:

```
      /// <summary>
    /// Declare POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) as you would to manipulate your inheritance
    /// </summary>
    public class Person
    {
        public abstract void Load();
        public abstract void Save();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simulate a consistent behavior
    /// </summary>
    public class Customer : Person
    {

        public override void Load()
        {
            // - Do some Linq2Sql stuff
        }

        public override void Save()
        {
            // - Do some Linq2Sql stuff
        }

    }
```

For queries like "JOIN", I would consider generating my own [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb397951.aspx),  if I really need this, cause this quickly becomes tricky.
The "Left Outer Join" method you see in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods) by **hajirazin** could also be put "protected" in class Person and called with right values from "Customer" and other children.

In conclusion, I think all the work has to be done manually to simulate requests in Objects. Expression trees could do everything but it is difficult to finalize.

Best regards,